# PHP function to convert HEX char codes to display equivalent

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am working on some PHP code to identify HEX character codes in a string and convert them to their "as seen on screen" equivalent. Mainly, there HEX codes are for accented characters like é, ç and so on.

For example, I am receiving a string like this:

$str = "caf&#xe9s"; - NOTE there is a semicolon after the 9 (i had to remove it to stop this text editor converting it!

The HEX part of the string is &#xe9 (again with semicolon at end) - and I am needing to convert that to its "as seen on screen" equivalent, in this case "é". So the converted string would be "cafés".

The following PHP code works, but I have to write one for each HEX code, and there are scores of them.

$keywords = str_replace("&#xe9","é",$keywords); [again the needle part has a semicolon]

Can anyone suggest an existing PHP function that can scan any string for known HEX codes and convert it to the display equivalent?

I am working in UTF8 otherwise.

Thanks for your consideration, sorry if my terminology sounds amateur.

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

This will convert HTML entities into their associated char

```
$keywords = html_entity_decode($keywords);
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I did wonder about that, but the output is showing little black diamonds with question marks, e.g. caf�s, I think this is something to do with encoding?

Comment: If you are outputting this to the browser, why do you need to use entity decode anyway?

Comment: Marcus, the output is going to the browser and also being stored in MySQL DB. I really need to have it decoded though, because I need to remove semicolons from the string (for a completely different reason) and this therefore corrupts the HEX code.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't put the version without semicolons in another variable? And display the one with semicolons?

Comment: Ah, I needed to use this: $keywords = html_entity_decode($keywords, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8"); due to older version of PHP. I think I am OK now. Thanks for the pointers.